# Trying to merge a specific range of cells in the last empty row, then paste a value into that cell

Tags: excel, vba

So, I'm trying to find the last empty row, and merge cells A:AH in that row, then paste contents into that merged cell.  I can sort of get it working, but my attempts to select the specific range of cells in the last row are not going well.  Anyone have any ideas?

Snip with notes commented out-

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Const PWD = "Password"


    'Time check
    Sheets("JC Input").Activate
    If IsEmpty(Range("Q3").Value) = True Then
        MsgBox "No Time Stamp!", vbOKCancel + vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Job Check
    Sheets("JC Input").Activate
    If IsEmpty(Range("D5").Value) = True Then
        MsgBox "No Job entered!", vbOKCancel + vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    With Worksheets("JC Input")
        
        .Range("B17").Copy 'Copy Cell
        Select Case .Range("L17").Value 'Dropdown Cell
            
        'Full Shop
        Case "11A Run Data, 11B Run Data"
            
            
        Worksheets("11A Run Data").Unprotect PWD
            Worksheets("JC Input").Range("B17").Copy
            Worksheets("11A Run Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                 
                 
                 'This works fine
                 
                 
                                    
        Worksheets("11B Run Data").Unprotect PWD
            Worksheets("JC Input").Range("B17").Copy
                lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
                        Worksheets("11B Run Data").Range("A" & lastrow & ":AH" & lastrow).Merge
                        Worksheets("11B Run Data").Range("A" & lastrow) = Worksheets("11B Run Data").Range("A1" & lastrow)
                    Worksheets("11B Run Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                 

               'Section above kind of works for merging, but doesn't paste into merged cells...  merges row 24 (Only row 24, but correct range of A:AH) and throws pastespecial range error 1004 on last line

                 'Also tried below, with no success

    Worksheets("11B Run Data").Unprotect PWD
        Worksheets("11B Run Data").Activate
               Worksheets("11B Run Data").Range("A:AH").End(xlDown).Select
               Worksheets("11B Run Data").ActiveCell.Merge
               
        Worksheets("JC Input").Range("B17").Copy
            lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
             Worksheets("11B Run Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying and pasting, you could just set the value to the merged cells.

```
Worksheets("11B Run Data").Unprotect PWD

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Dim mergeThis As Range
Set mergeThis = Worksheets("11B Run Data").Range("A" & lastrow & ":AH" & lastrow)
mergeThis.Merge

mergeThis = Worksheets("JC Input").Range("B17")
mergeThis.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter ' if you want it to be centered
```

As a side note, it is usually clearer and easier to declare some variables, like

```
Dim shRunData As Worksheet
Set shRunData = Worksheets("11B Run Data")
shRunData.Unprotect PWD

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Dim mergeThis As Range
' EDIT: to merge the row below the last row with content, add 1 to lastrow
' Set mergeThis = shRunData.Range("A" & lastrow & ":AH" & lastrow)
Set mergeThis = shRunData.Range("A" & lastrow + 1 & ":AH" & lastrow + 1)
mergeThis.Merge

Dim shInput As Worksheet
Set shInput = Worksheets("JC Input")
mergeThis = shInput.Range("B17")
mergeThis.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
```

Same code, but easier to maintain and spot bugs (specially if we consider the whole code you posted).

Comment: Worked, but its only merging/pasting on row 24?

Comment: @Humungotron I made an edit to set the merged rows to be the next row after `lastrow`. I don't know more details of your Worksheet data to help you further, but doing `ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)` will return the last cell of the Sheet that has or _had_ content, which may not be desirable.